# PHP reading CSV files in an odd order

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm using the the League CSV library, but the same exact thing happens when I use built in PHP functions. Here is my spreadsheet:

```
ID    column A  column B    column C
123   apple     orange      pear
```

And here is my code:

```
$stmt = (new Statement())
    ->offset(0)
    ->limit(2)
;

$records = $stmt->process($csv);
foreach ($records as $record) {
    print_r($record);
}
```

Finally, here is the output. Notice, the ID value (123) is hanging off to the left. I'm not even sure what that is supposed to mean.

```
Array 
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => column A
    [2] => column B
123 [3] => column C
    [4] => apple
    [5] => orange
    [6] => pear
)
```

Edit: Here is the raw CSV file. Newline character is possibly a carriage return?

```
ID,column A,column B,column C
123,apple,orange,pear
```

Comment: What does the CSV file look like "raw"? What's the newline character?

Comment: @mulquin see my edit

Comment: I expect its because you are assuming a column ends with a comma `,` but the last column in a row ends with a NewLine

Comment: Maybe if you showed us the code for the `Statement` class we could verify that

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's a huge library with a dozen separate files. This is so stupid, there's apparently no easy way to do this very basic function.

Comment: Who told you that it has to be simple. Processing plain text is never simple

Comment: Basically you are not processing the last column in a line correctly. Whatever that class does, it either is not up to the job, or you have not correctly told it that the last column in a row ends in a NewLine and not a Comma

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your file has `LF` as the newline character, but the library expects `CRLF`, so it thinks this is just one long line.

Comment: This would happen if the file was created on Unix but you're running the script on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This was really lame. Since I'm on a Mac, I needed to add this line to the top of the script:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
```